# Suppressing newline in python 2.x when setting a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda:([],[],[]))
```

I am iterating through a file and setting variable equal to lines and then appending to a dictionary like this:

```
for i in file:
    x = i
    my_dict[key][0].append(x)
```

But when adding like the following I get the new line appended to the string:

```
my_dict[key][1].append(x)
```

I know that a comma suppresses the newline when printing, but how about in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Googling anything about removing or stripping newlines or linefeeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your newlines come from your file, they were not added by Python. Remove them as you load the line from the file:

```
for i in file:
    x = i.rstrip('\n')
    my_dict[key][0].append(x)
```